Issue installing griddb-node-api on Ubuntu with GridDB v5.5 and Node.js v20.11
I'm facing an issue while trying to install the griddb-node-api package on my Ubuntu system.
I'm following the installation guide from the [official GridDB documentation]
(https://docs.griddb.net/latest/gettingstarted/nodejs/) and using the command:
npm i griddb-node-api



I have ensured that all prerequisites mentioned in the documentation are met. Despite this, the installation fails, and I'm not sure how to resolve this issue.
I have followed the same documentation for GridDB-Node-Api:

Here's the full error message for reference:


What I've Tried:

Rechecking the versions of Node.js and GridDB to ensure compatibility.
Following the troubleshooting steps mentioned in the documentation.

Specifics of my setup:

Operating System: Ubuntu ,
GridDB Version: 5.5 ,
Node.js Version: 20.11

Questions:

What could be causing this installation error?
Are there any known compatibility issues with Node.js v20.11 and GridDB v5.5?
Is there a workaround or a specific configuration required to successfully install griddb-node-api on Ubuntu?

Any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I just want to quick verify: are you using Ubuntu or Windows? because your error codes seem to show Windows-related error codes. I quickly tried the npm command on my macos and it worked fine

I'm using Windows and installing this with WSL documentation.
https://docs.griddb.net/latest/gettingstarted/wsl/#installing-griddb

I'm wondering are you actually using the WSL or just the windows prompt? what happens if you type cat /etc/lsb-release ?

Getting
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.0.4 LTS"
